# How to calculate closeness centrality of nodes in a graph, toward some special nodes in networkx?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

Based on the definition,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             I know that In a connected graph, closeness centrality calculated as the sum of the length of the shortest paths between the node and all other nodes in the graph, and I am using Networkx library to calculate this parameter in my code based on the blow command:

```
nx.closeness_centrality(G,i)
```

But I want to find closeness centrality based on the shortest path between node "i" and a predefined set of nodes, not All nodes

how can I reach this? is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

old question and you might have already find the answer but I will run the the command above for all the nodes and then find the set nodes with the keys you want to target.

Answer (score 0):

Closeness centrality based on shortest between few selected nodes? If I understood it correctly then you must find distance between those nodes individually.

```
closeness_centrality = sum(all_distances)**(-1)
```